# jQuery access java Map of string object where the object is a map of strings

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsonp

I am trying to return two json sets from java which each contain key/value pairs. I can get the data to return as expected but once I have the data I can not access it properly. Here is what my data coming from the java looks like

```
{"RESULTS":
    {"MAP_1":
       [
         {"value":"1","display":"output text","type":"type a"},
         {"value":"2","display":"more output text","type":"type a"}
        ],
      "MAP_2":
        [
         {"value":"1","display":"output text","type":"type b"},
         {"value":"2","display":"more output text","type":"type b"}
         ]
     }
}
```

I have tried using $.map and $.each but I can not seem to drill into the data any help would be greatly appeciated.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
         searchString: request.term
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.MAP_1, function( item ) {
            label: item.value + ", " + item.type
                value: item.display
        }));
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the data returned by java is **text**, not **json**. So you should specify the **dataType** as **json**.  In addition the following code are not right, I think.

```
data.MAP_1
```

should be

```
data.RESULTS.MAP_1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have been beating my head over this for the past hour or so.